# conversion from void pointer to pointer to struct or class

Tags: c++, c++14

what is the correct approach for converting void * to pointer to struct or class.

sometime mistakes can happen like pointer to different class or struct was assigned.how to catch these types of mistakes over compile or run time.

following program tried, surprisingly it compiled and no crash even after execution.

what is right way for type casting from void * to pointer to struct or class in cpp

Description:
how to avoid type casting related issues from void * to pointer to class or struct at compile time or runtime. if static_cast is used for conversion from void * then code is compiled, even it is invalid conversion.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct stu
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

struct clg
{
    int x;
    float y;
    char z;
};

void fun(void *msg)
{
    clg *myclg = static_cast<clg*>(msg);

    cout<<"casting is done."<<endl;

}

int main()
{
    stu* st = new stu();
    clg* cl = new clg();

    void *ptr = st;
    fun(ptr);
    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The right way is not to cast the pointer to `void*` in the first place. `void fun(clg* msg) { cout << "done" << endl; }`. Now, if you try to call `fun(st)`, you get an error.

Comment: try using msg inside fun

Comment: You cannot catch such mistakes. You need to avoid making them in the first place.

Comment: Even if it compiles or runs successfully, there are possible UB (undefined behavior) errors. You should know the pitfalls about casting itself, especially pointers, and aliasing, when doing such things.

Comment: "how to catch these types of mistakes over compile or run time" there is no way to do that. See, the problem with void pointer that it is not type safe. When you are using it, you essentially are telling the compiler that that pointer is pointing to the type you are casting to. And the time you use it, all responsibility for proper types are on you. So the best way to use it is to not.

Comment: You could add a base class for all your classes then you can cast from void* to your base class then dynamic cast to the expected class

Comment: @AlanBirtles Dynamic cast does not work unless you have virtual functions.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili yes, you'd have to add a virtual destructor to the base class

Answer (score 0):

You can't type check a void pointer. It points to a memory address but you are responsible for managing the size of the memory chunk it points to. In other words, void* doesn't give more information than : this is a memory address. Compare to a char* that holds the information : this is a memory address and from this address to the next 7 bits address, is one chunk of data. Now, that's very unsafe, but in most cases, you shouldn't find yourself using one (unless you're coding legacy c++ but given the c++14 tag, I reckon it isn't the case).

void* was used to implement generic functions in case you didn't know the type of data that was going to be used. There are essentially two solutions to get around it : heritage and templates.

There are cases when you will have to use void pointers. One of them would be when interfacing with C code as C will only take generic pointers. Another use case would be when you don't care about the data format (memcpy for exemple). But then, no type casting is needed here.

Comment: On a side note: Since C++17 `std::byte` is used for binary data of arbitrary type. Up to C++14 (and sometimes also for later versions) often `char` or `unsigned char` (but not `signed char`, which is not necessarily the same as `char`!) are used for this purpose. So a pointer to one of those types could be preferable to `void*`.